# Independence of Random Variables ( Measure Theory)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Bbb Ω,\Bbb F,μ)$ be a probability measure space (that is $μ(\Bbb Ω)=1$),  $f:\Bbb Ω \rightarrow \Bbb R$ , a $\Bbb F$-measurable function (random variable) and $φ:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ a Borel measurable function. We have to show that the family $(φ\circ f,f)$ is independent iff $φ\circ f$ is constanst $μ$-a.e.

If we suppose that $φ\circ f$ and $f$ are independent then we know that the σ-algebras $$σ(f)=f^{-1}(\mathcal{B} (\Bbb R))$$
$$σ(φ\circ f)=(φ\circ f)^{-1}(\mathcal B(\Bbb R))$$ 
are independent. We observe that $$σ(φ\circ f)=(φ\circ f)^{-1}(\mathcal B(\Bbb R))=f^{-1}(φ^{-1}(\mathcal B(\Bbb R))\subset f^{-1}(\mathcal B(\Bbb R))=σ(f)$$
So, if we pick an $A$ in $σ(f\circ φ)$ we have also picked an $A$ at $σ( f)$. Then $(A,A)$ is an independent family. This implies that $μ(Α)=0$ or $μ(A)=1$. This is where i'm stuck. I have and some other thoughts but i think that this is the right starting point. Any help would be great. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes i'm sorry. I define then the Borel measure $ν: \mathcal B (\Bbb R) \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ with $ν(A)= μ((φοf)^{-1} (A))$ and we observe that this can take only the values 0 and 1. Then we have a result that tells us that when this happens this Borel measure is exactly a Dirac measure for some $x_{o}\in \Bbb R$. Then i'm a bit confused on how to proceed. Also i don''t have the opposite direction at all.

Comment: I had misread your question — you said what you were trying to do at the start of the question. My mistake. Btw, please use `\circ` for $\circ$ to denote function composition.

Comment: Also, the reverse direction is easy. Constants are independent of everything (even themselves).

Comment: @Odidron You have that $\nu = \delta_y$ for some $y$. Let $B = \{\omega\in\Omega : (\varphi\circ f)(\omega)\neq y\} = (\varphi\circ f)^{-1}(\mathbb R\setminus\{y\})$. Then $\mu(B) = \nu(\mathbb R\setminus\{y\}) = \delta_y(\mathbb R\setminus\{y\}) = 0$. So, $\varphi\circ f = y$ $\mu$-a.e.